# Reference unit tests for common data structures?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm writing a class library that contains several specialized implementations of common data structures (lists, sets, dictionaries...). I find myself always writing the same unit tests over and over, and I'm never sure I'm not forgetting to test some important scenarios.

Since my classes all implement standard interfaces (`IList<T>`, `IDictionary<K,V>`, etc), I was wondering if there were some kind of "reference" unit tests that all implementations of these interfaces should pass. Of course I would also need to test the specific aspects of my classes, but at least I would be more confident that there is nothing broken in my implementation of the standard interfaces.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I know about these tools, but my library targets .NET 3.5, so I can't use them... Anyway, they're not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Mono unit tests on Github](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/corlib/Test/System.Collections.Generic) - there is at least `Dictionary` and `IList` tests there already.