# IList implementation testing

Tags: c#, generics, ilist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference unit tests for common data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253943/reference-unit-tests-for-common-data-structures)

I'm trying to implement the IList interface. I've finished my implementation, but I'm not sure if my implementation semantically fits for this interface. Are there tests for prooving that? Tests for the ICollection interface would be appreciate too.

Comment: Have you tried writing unit tests for the class implementing this interface?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes, mono tests looks like that I seeking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what you're supposed to implement so just unit test your class.

There are no 'standard' tests for collections in BCL, as every collection is different. Yours must be doing something special since you're not using `List<T>`.

Comment: I need my implementation to work absolutely like Generic.List since they both implement IList interface. I was wondering if there is tests for testing all implementation of IList to work like Generic.List